# Tauri compilation error: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: npm, memory, rust, webview2, tauri

I'm trying to use [`create-tauri-app`](https://npmjs.com/package/create-tauri-app) to set up Tauri (for the first time) on my computer. I initialized it with `npm create tauri-app`, followed all the prompts and successfully created a project. After moving into the generated directory (I have not modified *anything*) and running `npm i`, I attempt to run `npm run tauri dev`, as instructed from the prompts by the app generator. Vite started successfully, and after a painfully long compilation of a bunch of cargo packages, I suddenly see this message in the terminal:

```
error: could not compile `tauri`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name tauri --edition=2021 C:\Users\[...]\tauri-1.0.5\src\lib.rs [... redacted because way too long]`
  (exit code: 0xc0000005, STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
```

(...and the program crashes with lots of npm junk)

*Note: this error was produced by Tauri or some third-party package. I have no control over the code from which the error originates.*
I've double-checked everything and spent hours retrying, googling, restarting my computer, and other junk all to no avail. I understand `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` has something to do with memory being messed up (seems also to be an error code common in Chromium, so I suspect the culprit is webview2), but I have no idea how to pinpoint the issue.

If helpful, here's my system details as provided by running `npx tauri info`:

```
Environment
  › OS: Windows 10.0.18363 X64
  › Webview2: 104.0.1293.47
  › MSVC: 
      - Visual Studio Build Tools 2017
  › Node.js: 14.16.1
  › npm: 6.14.12
  › pnpm: 6.11.0
  › yarn: 1.22.15
  › rustup: 1.25.1
  › rustc: 1.62.1
  › cargo: 1.62.1
  › Rust toolchain: stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu 

Packages
  › @tauri-apps/cli [NPM]: 1.0.5
  › @tauri-apps/api [NPM]: 1.0.2
  › tauri [RUST]: 1.0.5,
  › tauri-build [RUST]: 1.0.4,
  › tao [RUST]: 0.12.2,
  › wry [RUST]: 0.19.0,

App
  › build-type: bundle
  › CSP: unset
  › distDir: ../dist
  › devPath: http://localhost:5173/
  › framework: Vue.js

App directory structure
  ├─ .vscode
  ├─ node_modules
  ├─ public
  ├─ src
  └─ src-tauri
```

And here's the `package.json` for anyone who's interested:

```json
{
  "name": "tauri-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "tauri": "tauri"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tauri-apps/api": "^1.0.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.37"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tauri-apps/cli": "^1.0.5",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vite": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

As you can see, I've installed all the required items and nothing seems out of place. Has anyone faced this issue before or have any ideas on how to fix this? I'm desperate to find a solution.

### Update

After following a suggestion from a comment that I should be using the `msvc` Rust toolchain instead of the `gnu`, the original error is no longer present, but I have a completely different mysterious error about my OS not being supported (`Os { code: 216, kind: Uncategorized, message: "This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher." }`), so this question is no longer awaiting answers (unless you know how to fix the most recent said issue, please comment).

Comment: Make sure rust is updated. rustc should not be crashing.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I just updated it yesterday; as you can see from my system details rustc is v1.62.1.

Comment: Access violation is your process attempting to read or write to memory that isn't allowed for read/write. If you run your process under a native debugger (VS or windbg) you can see the crash stack and identify where the issue is coming from.

Comment: @DavidRisney no expert at memory stuff, but I didn't directly launch the program that crashed; it was a subprocess started by Tauri, where Rust attempted to compile something, which likely tried to start something else that crashed. I'm open to trying anything though, although I don't have windbag or VS, nor do I know how to use it.

Comment: I don't know Tauri, but given that it reports the VS tools version, maybe you should use the `stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` target instead of `stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu`?

Comment: @Jmb what would that do, and how would I do it?

Comment: @code it would use the MSVC toolchain instead of the GNU toolchain. Assuming you've installed Rust with `rustup`, you can make it use the MSVC toolchain with `rustup default stable-msvc` (you might need to run `rustup target add x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` if the target isn't already installed).

Comment: @Jmb thanks for the suggestion. The error I mentioned has been replaced by a new one, so I guess that solves the issue :)

Comment: @code do you have a solution for the new error you are getting? I am unable to find one

Comment: @DerrickAwuah sorry, no. Perhaps I should post a new question? Did you find out anything? I'm just stuck here on this project; thankfully it's just a side project, but I still want it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Visual Studio Build Tools version 2019 or greater. I was also getting this error with build tools 2017 and installing 2022 resolved it.

Step one of the [getting started](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/getting-started/prerequisites/#setting-up-windows) guide for windows says to install 2022. I believe any version after 2019 will work but I would recommend 2022 as that's what the guide suggests.

[Visual Studio Build Tools 2022](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)

Comment: Thanks so much for you answer. I just got to update msbuild to 2022 and it finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

you need to delete the target directory and restart the project so that it'clean            and no error remains.

Comment: I don't believe that's working.